# layout.js updated after compile sails lift

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have new in `sails.js` . In `layout.js` in views files I have script tags like this.

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I have changed the file and move the file jquery.min.js to the top and compile usings `sails lift`.
Then my `layout.js` changed and file remain same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every script between

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

will get modified automatically by the grunt task which will parse your assets folder and put reference to every script it finds there overwriting your file. If you wish to put your script above all else, modify your pipeline.js file in the tasks folder - look for the variable jsFilesToInject and put your jquery.min.js file above all else or just move that file into /js/dependencies/jquery folder in your project.